# Do loop until 2 things in column do not equal. Pulling information from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to pull information from another sheet and then have it check to make sure 2 cells in this sheet are not the same. It is for a randomized meal plan, but on the same day you can not eat the same protein (to give you a little background). I have the code checking to see if it can be used during that meal and if it can be it is put into the next sheet. It does this for lunch and dinner. It is getting caught in the do - loop until loop and I am not sure how to solve this.

If you need anymore information I can provide screenshots if this does not make sense.

```
Do

RandNumLunch = Int((10 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)

Do Until Sheet2.Cells(RandNumLunch, 6) = "Yes"
    If Sheet2.Cells(RandNumLunch, 6) = "Yes" Then
    Else
    RandNumLunch = Int((10 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)
    End If
Loop

If Sheet2.Cells(RandNumLunch, 6) = "Yes" Then
    Sheet3.Cells(3, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(RandNumLunch, 1)
End If



RandNumDinner = Int((10 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)

Do Until Sheet2.Cells(RandNumDinner, 7) = "Yes"
    If Sheet2.Cells(RandNumDinner, 7) = "Yes" Then
Else
    RandNumDinner = Int((10 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)
End If
Loop

If Sheet2.Cells(RandNumDinner, 7) = "Yes" Then
    Sheet3.Cells(4, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(RandNumLunch, 1)
End If

Loop Until Sheet3.Cells(4, 2) <> Sheet3.Cells(3, 2)
```

Comment: In order to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please edit your question and post some sample data that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? Should I post screenshots of the different sheets?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to randomise a set of cells value onto another sheet but not on the same row? Use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx) or [ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) object to build up unique list, retrieve from it randomly, if not existed in target worksheet, place it in and remove from Dictionary/ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

In your final `If..Else`, you use `RandNumLunch` where you should be using `RandNumDinner`. This means that the whatever happens in between, you set `Sheet3.Cells(3, 2)` and `Sheet3.Cells(4, 2)` to the same value, so the final check can never be true.